# fetching data from api/db

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm trying to fetch data i have stored on sql , but everytime i try to fetch the data nothing shows and in my console i get error

> 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'

The code below is the controller that handles the request to fetch the data from the database :

```
final getMealProvider = FutureProvider<List<MenuModel>>((ref) async {
  return ref.watch(chefMenuProvider).getMeals();
});

final chefMenuProvider = Provider((ref) => MealController());

class MealController {

  Future<List<MenuModel>> getMeals() async {
    try {
      final res = await http.get(Uri.parse(API.getChefMenu));
      List<MenuModel> menu = jsonDecode(res.body);
      return menu;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return []; // Return an empty list or handle the error case appropriately
    }
  }
}
```

the below is where i want to display the fetched data :

```
 body: menuAsync.when(
            data: (data) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    final e = data[index];
                    return Column(
                      children: [Text(e.mealName)],
                    );
                  });
            },
            error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorText(error: error.toString()),
            loading: () => const Loader()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will describe the actions:

1. In this case you get a `Response` here:

```dart
final http.Response res = await http.get(Uri.parse(API.getChefMenu));
```

2. Next, this line must be decoded and cast as `List`:

```dart
final List<dynamic> body = json.decode(res.body) as List;
```

3. Another conversion of internal data:

```dart
final bodyJson = body.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
```

4. Just use the `fromJson` method and tear-off:

```dart
List<MenuModel> menu = bodyJson.map(MenuModel.fromJson).toList();
```

Comment: tried this but now i instead get  type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Comment: So make an extra check for null where this error occurs.

Comment: This error occurs when you getting 'Null' from API where you declared a String.So please check both side which variable type mismatch. if you get null then check first null or not

Answer (score 0):

if your response List data comes with the name 'data'

```
List<MenuModel> menu  = (jsonDecode(response.body)['data'] as List)
                .map((item) => MenuModel.fromJson(item))
                .toList();
```

or if the response comes directly in response.body

```
List<MenuModel> menu  = (jsonDecode(response.body) as List)
                .map((item) => MenuModel.fromJson(item))
                .toList();
```

or if you dont have any MenuModel.fromJson() function then u can directly store the data like this

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> jsonData = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
List<MenuModel> menu = [];

 for (var item in jsonData) {
   MenuModel mm = MenuModel(item);
   Menu.add(mm);
}
```